# How to escape HQL special column "index" in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entities like this:

```
class Index{
}

class Foo {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumns{....}
    private Set<Bar> bars;
}

class Bar{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="index_id")
    private Index index;
}
```

Every thing is fine if I write the HQL `from Bar bar join fetch bar.index`.  However if I try to do

```
from Foo foo 
join fetch foo.bars bar
join fetch bar.index
```

Hibernate assumed the "index" is the collection index of `bar` as in `foo.bars`, which caused an exception something like

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Property index does not exist in collection foo.Foo.bars; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Property index does not exist in collection foo.Foo.bars
```

Is there anyway that I can tell Hibernate that I am not looking for that "special" property, but just the normal field that I have mapped?

(I have read through several previous questions which talks about escaping keywords by using backticks or square brackets.  However they only works for the mapped column being a keywords. In my case it is not working)

Comment: I would simply choose another name for the class and for the attribute. index is also a SQL keyword, and you're asking for trouble by using this name. Why not use Position, for example?

Comment: @JBNizet The reason is there is no better choice of word here :P  Index here is not the index as a position.  It is the Index as described here: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/index.asp

Comment: Of course renaming the stuff is a possible workaround (I have taken another workaround already) but I am more keen on knowing if there is proper way to deal with such situation.